# Unzip an agent into the population of a different agent it contains

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent called Pallet that moves throughout a factory. It contains a population of 200 Product agents. When a pallet gets to a production line, I am trying to get the pallet to unload or unzip into the 200 products, and the pallet agent itself can be destroyed. Just the 200 products should move through the production line.

Could anyone advise on how to achieve this?

To empty the Pallet of the product, I can do

```
`while ( product.size() > 0 ){
        remove_product( product.get( 0 ) );
}`
```

but I need the product to continue existing and move down the line and the pallet can be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Unbatch](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/unbatch.html#unbatch) block, that is its purpose.

Note that you need to prepare the `Pallet` agent previously via a `Batch` block. But if you check the example models in the help, this is very easy to do